# can't access MySQL database for Drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, phpmyadmin

I just installed an instance of Drupal on a shared web hosting account earlier today (via softaculous). I set some things different from how I wanted it the first time, so I deleted the directory it installed in, and the database and user that were created for it, and then tried again. Shortly after starting to work with the second install, I got the error described below, and I hadn't done much yet so I re-installed again. Now I'm on my third install, with all three using the same database and user name (I deleted the old MySQL database and user through cPanel before each install), and the same error is happening again.

When I try to access any of the drupal pages, I get this:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
'mareofni_twocit'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of
home/mareofni/public_html/twocities/includes/lock.inc).
```

The "MySQL Databases" section of cPanel says that the database and user still exist. When I use the "check database" feature, it gives this error message:

```
Error from MySQL query: DBD::mysql::db do failed:
Unknown database 'mareofni_twocit'Failed to use
mareofni_twocit: Unknown database 'mareofni_twocit'
```

"Repair database" in cPanel doesn't fix the problem, and gives the same error message.

```
Error from MySQL query: DBD::mysql::db do failed:
Unknown database 'mareofni_twocit'Failed to use
mareofni_twocit: Unknown database 'mareofni_twocit'
```

I tried looking at the databse in phpMyAdmin, but phpMyAdmin doesn't list the database - like it can't tell that it exists.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem myself, or prevent it happening again the next time I install Drupal? Some insight on what the problem *is* would also be helpful.

(Line breaks in the error messages are mine, added for readability.)

Comment: Well, I'm gonna go with those exact errors. The database does not exist. And the username doesn't exist either. Odds are they're correct.

Comment: @Andrew Do you have any idea how the database could've gotten deleted? It definitely existed before, since Drupal was connecting to it with no errors an hour ago.

Comment: No idea mate. I'm looking at errors here, not code.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that I cannot create database users who are able to drop databases, and the user I access phpMyAdmin through also cannot drop databases. Since phpMyAdmin couldn't find the database at all, I think the database must have been dropped or corrupted (rather than all the tables dropped or something).

This can't be something that Drupal did, since the Drupal user didn't have permission to drop the database. (Unless Drupal managed to *corrupt* the database somehow; I don't know enough about how that works to be sure of whether it's possible.) I suspect there's a bug in cPanel, Softaculous, or some other software put there by the hosting company that caused it. Maybe it didn't like that I re-created the DB immediately after deleting it.

I'm trying again with a different database name and crossing my fingers.